# If value not found after login, logout user?

Tags: angular, authentication

I am trying to save user details in local storage so, when the user login and on the home page value i.e. **username is not found user should be logout with alert and clear local storage** too. but I have less clue how to do this using Angular?

checking **if the username is undefined then it should be logout**

on the Home page, after login, I am storing data -
**main.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string | undefined;
    
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let date: Date = new Date();
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userid')
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username')

  }

  CheckLogin() {
    if(this.username = undefined){
    alert('please login again');
  }
}
```

in **main.html**

I call my function on submit button

```
<input class="submit-btn" type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" (click) = "CheckLogin()" value="Submit">
```

if the username is undefined it should show an alert but the alert is also not showing.

I am generally mean if there is any method to check if the page does not have username value then it will show alert and logout user?

the login page is working fine and it takes user data and store in local storage.

Comment: is checklogin really inside OnInit? besides the assignment `=`

Comment: yes it is inside OnInit

Comment: How do you expect the function be called from inside OnInit? :)

Comment: Also where are the curly brackets for the constructor?  I'm surprised your code even compiles?

Comment: I have updated the code please check @AJT82

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
 if(this.username == undefined){
 alert('please login again');}
```

You have made an assignation not a condition

Comment: oops! that was my typo == is still there but not working

Comment: What is the outpout when you make a

`console.log(this.username)`

Comment: not showing even a alert!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your thought behind how you have implemented your code. Please refer to the documentation at angular.io to learn the basics of Angular. Constructor is for example used for initialization of variables. OnInit is called after component is initialized, any functions should not be placed inside there.

Your code should look like:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  let date: Date = new Date();
  this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userid')
  this.username = localStorage.getItem('username')
}

CheckLogin(){
  if(this.username === undefined){
    alert('please login again');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your issue is the use of the [assignment operator (=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) vs the [equality operator (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality).

Beyond the basics, typically security is done using angular guards which implement [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).  These can prevent users from activating a component and redirect them to another component (say the login screen).  There is [more then enough content](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) on the internet about angular and route guards, that providing any code here is basically useless.

Additionally, I'd highly recommend you use a State Library instead of directly talking to a storage system.  Simply being that as your code stands no components knows if the username goes blank or any other value that you may share between components changes.  In no particular order there are [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/), [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/), [Akida](https://medium.com/swlh/angular-state-management-with-akita-b4c5439c1ab5) just to name a couple.